# Prove that $\inf _{n \geq k} (a_n + b_n) \geq \inf _{n \geq k} (a_n) + \inf _{n \geq k} (b_n) (\forall k)$

Tags: real-analysis

I understand that

$\inf _{n \geq k}  a_n \leq a_n (\forall n \geq k)$

$\inf _{n \geq k}  b_n \leq b_n (\forall n \geq k)$

Thus

$\inf _{n \geq k}  a_n + \inf _{n \geq k}  b_n \leq a_n + b_n (\forall n \geq k)$

I'm not too sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $k$. for any $N\ge k$, it holds that
$$\inf_{n\ge k}a_n+\inf_{n\ge k}{b_n}\le a_N+b_N.$$
So $\inf_{n\ge k}a_n+\inf_{n\ge k}{b_n}$ is a lower bound of the set $\{a_N+b_N:\, N\ge k\}$. Since $\inf$ is the ``best'' lower bound, it follows that
$$\inf_{n\ge k}a_n+\inf_{n\ge k}{b_n}\le\inf_{N\ge k}(a_N+b_N).$$

Answer (score 0):

Your last line states that $\inf_{n\geq k}a_{n}+\inf_{n\geq k}b_{n}$ is a **lower bound** of the set $\{a_n+b_n\mid n\geq k\}$.

Then it is legal to conclude that it does not exceed the **greatest lower bound** of that set.

So in mathematical notation: $$\inf_{n\geq k}a_{n}+\inf_{n\geq k}b_{n}\leq\inf_{n\geq k}(a_n+b_n)\text{ QED}$$